# Set minimal reasonable width for a QScrollArea

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qscrollarea

I am relatively new to Qt, which I access through PySide.

I have a longish list of content that I want to make vertically scrollable.
The horizontal size is not an issue. I tried using `QScrollArea` for that. Here is a minimal example:

```
import sys

import PySide.QtGui as gui

application = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = gui.QScrollArea()
list = gui.QWidget()
layout = gui.QVBoxLayout(list)

for i in range(100):
    layout.addWidget(gui.QLabel(
        "A something longish, slightly convoluted example text."))

window.setWidget(list)

window.show()

sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

What happens:

1. The scroll-area sets its horizontal size to the size needed for the labels
2. It notices that the vertical space is insufficient, so it adds a vertical scrollbar.
3. Due to the vertical scrollbar, the horizontal space is now insufficient as well, and so the horizontal scrollbar is also shown.

I can make the horizontal scrollbar go away with `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy`, but the main problem persists: the vertical scrollbar obscures part of the labels.

How can I set the width of the scroll-area to the minimal value which does not need a horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is somewhat unrealistic, because the scroll-area is made the top-level window. More typically, it would be a child widget, and its initial size would be determined by a layout, and would be indirectly constrained by the sizes of other widgets and/or layouts. As a top-level window, the constraints are different, and partly under the influence of the window-manager (the exact behaviour of which can vary between platforms).

To ensure that the scroll-area has the correct size, you must set a minimum width for it, based on its contents, and also allowing for the vertical scrollbar and the frame. It is also probably best to set the [widgetResizable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) property to `True` and add an expandable spacer to the end of the contents layout.

In the example below, I have changed the background colour of the labels to make it easier to see what is going on. I have also allowed resizing the window smaller than its initial size, by resetting the minimum width after it is shown - but that is optional.

```
import sys

import PySide.QtGui as gui

application = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = gui.QScrollArea()
window.setWidgetResizable(True)
list = gui.QWidget()
layout = gui.QVBoxLayout(list)

# just for testing
window.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: red}')

for i in range(30):
    layout.addWidget(gui.QLabel(
        "A something longish, slightly convoluted example text."))

layout.addStretch()

window.setWidget(list)

window.setMinimumWidth(
    list.sizeHint().width() +
    2 * window.frameWidth() +
    window.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())

window.show()

# allow resizing smaller
window.setMinimumWidth(1)

sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes, the QScrollArea being the main window is part of the example's minimality. In the real application it is inside a QStackedWidget.

Comment: @kne. Either way, my answer is the correct solution. Did you actually try it?

Comment: It works fine, thank you. I only do not understand why. IIUC, `list.layout().getContentsMargins()[2]` is equivalent to `layout.contentsMargins().right()`. How about the left margin? Visually, there are margins in all four directions. Is the left margin already included in `window.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()`?

Comment: @kne. Yes, I made a silly error because the layout contents margin is coincidentally twice the width of the scroll-area's frame. I have corrected my answer, so hopefully it now makes complete sense.

Comment: Thank you again. I did not realize that there is an intermediate class (QFrame in this case) between QWidget and QAbstractScrollArea. The PySide documentation does not exactly make it easy to identify ancestors (and thus complete method lists). Your correction was an eye-opener!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sizeHint() in the widgets and use the result to set the minimum width of the QScrollArea.

Some extra info here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that would not include the space necessary for the vertical scrollbar, the frame and the margins.

Comment: You're right. The space for the vertical scrollbar is not accounted. I forgot to add this in my previous comment.